# Boost search results based on tags

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ElasticSearch with a bunch of TV episodes indexed.

Each episode is tagged with an array of tags describing the key features of the content.

Now I want to implement a "similar to" functionality where I want to search all episodes that have a maximum overlap of tags (but not necessarily all) for a given episode.

Example:

```
Original Episode Tags: ["a","b","c","d"]

Some Other Episode 1: ["a","b"] // should match, 2 matching tags
Some Other Episode 2: ["a","b","c","x","y"] // should match higher, 3 matching tags 
Some Other Episode 2: ["a"] // should match lower, only 1 matching tags
Some Other Episode 3: ["e","f","g"] // shouldn't match, no matching tags
```

I tried using a boolean query with a `should` clause but the problem is that once I reach the `minimum_should_match` requirement the document matches and the rest of the clauses seem to be ignored from the score calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a terms query/filter with a specified boost

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "terms": {
        "Tags": ["a", "b", "c","d"],
        "boost": 1
      }
   }
 }
}
```

So the score for 1 would be 2, 2 would be 3 and so on

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the (a) right way to do it:

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {"term":{"tags":"a"}},
                        {"term":{"tags":"b"}},
                        {"term":{"tags":"c"}}
                    ]
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {"filter":{"term":{"tags":"a"}},"weight": 5},
                {"filter":{"term":{"tags":"b"}},"weight": 5},
                {"filter":{"term":{"tags":"c"}},"weight": 5}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

the `should` clause makes sure that at least one tag matches on the matching document whereas the `functions` clause boosts the score of the matching document by 5 for every matching tag.